# flat base change and finitely generated

Tags: commutative-algebra

Given that $R\to S$ is a flat local ring homomorphism of two Noetherian local rings. Then is $S$ always a finitely generated $R$-module?

This question stems from a small detail in a proof I am currently reading, which asserts that given the above hypothesis and $Y$ is a finitely generated $R$-module, then they conclude that $S\otimes_R Y$ is a finitely generated $R$-module. This is why I have the above question.

Can you explain this for me? Thank you

Comment: For a Noetherian local ring $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ the map $R\to \widehat{R}$, the $\mathfrak{m}$-adic completion is always flat, but the latter is seldom a finitely generated $R$-module.

Comment: $S \otimes_R Y$ should be finitely generated as an $S$-module, not necessarily as an $R$-module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\mathbb Q \hookrightarrow \mathbb C$$